# Does OpenGL allow you to provide array attributes when using glMultiDrawArrays?

Tags: opengl

I'm drawing a bunch of primitives (in my case lines) using the `glMultiDrawArrays` command. Each of these arrays (lines) have some additional attribute(s) specific to that array.

I would essentially like to pass these "array attributes" as separate `uniform`s specific to each array.

The two ways I can think of now is:

1. Draw each array (line) in separate draw calls and specify the attribute as a `uniform`.
2. Pass these attributes as vertex attributes. This would require me to store as many copies of the same value as I have vertices (I can have up to a 100k in the arrays). Not an option if I do have to store them!

Is there a smarter way of doing this in OpenGL?

Say I have `n` number of primitives to draw. 
The `glMultiDrawArrays` command already requires me to pass along two arrays of size `n`. One array (`lineStartIndex`) of start indices and one array (`lineCount`) storing how many vertices each array contains .

To me it seems as it should be possible to specify vertex array attributes in a similar manner. E.g. a `arrayAttributes` vector of size `n` that could also be passed along with the draw call.

So instead of `vertexAttribArray` I'd like something like `vertexArrayAttribArray` ;)

Btw, I am only using one VAO and one VBO.

Answer (score 0):

> To me it seems as it should be possible to specify vertex array attributes in a similar manner.

Why? Vertex attributes are for things that change per-vertex; why would you expect to be able to use them for things that *don't* change per-vertex?

Well, you *can* (as I will explain), but I don't know why you think it should be possible.

The [instancing and base instance feature](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing) can be (ab)used to provide a uniform-like value to a shader in a draw call.

You need to set up the attribute you want to provide "per-line" as an [instanced array attribute](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Instanced_Array). So you would use `glVertexAttribDivisor` with a value of 1 for that attribute.

Then, for each line, you would call `glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance`. Each call represents a single line, so you would provide an instance count of 1. But the base instance represents the index in the attribute array for that line's "per-line" value.

Yes, you're not using multi-draw. But OpenGL's draw call overhead is minimal; it's combining draw calls with state changes that get you. And you're not changing state between calls, so there's no problem.

However, if you're concerned about this minor overhead, and have access to [multi-draw indirect](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Indirect_rendering) functionality, you can always use that. Each line is a separate draw in the multi-draw call.

Of course, base instance requires GL 4.2 or ARB_base_instance. If you don't have access to hardware of this nature, then you're going to have to stick with the `uniform` variable method.

Comment: _Why? Vertex attributes are for things that change per-vertex; why would you expect to be able to use them for things that don't change per-vertex?_
That's not what I'm saying. I'm not talking about 'vertexAttribArrays' I mean something like 'vertexArrayAttribArray'.
I also edited that line in my original post to maybe clarify what I meant.

Comment: @c'Bam: "*I mean something like (vertex)'ArrayAttribArray'*" I don't know what that's supposed to mean. And, as you may notice, rendering commands do not specify the attributes. At all; they come from the VAO.